# Why does view caching in CakePHP 2.2.4 cause a blank white page after a view is cached?

Tags: cakephp, caching, view

I am updating a CakePHP 1.3 app to 2.2.4 and have followed the steps outlined in the CakePHP Book 2.0 for turning on view caching. View caching has been working perfectly in the 1.3 app, but when I turn it on in the 2.2.4 app, each view will display initially. However, once the view is cached, any subsequent attempt to load that view results in a blank page with no source code and no error messages.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

1. Experimented with changing the debug level from 0 to 1 and to 2.
2. Double-checked my bootstrap file to make sure the CacheDispatcher is loaded.
3. Double-checked my AppController for public $helpers = array('Cache');
4. Double-checked my AppController for public $cacheAction = true;
5. chmod the tmp folders, subfolders and files to 777.
6. Checked the debug and error logs for errors and found nothing.
7. Apache error and access logs also show no errors.

If I delete the cached view from tmp/cache/views, and then reload the page it displays fine. But then another reload results in a blank page because the view was cached. Any idea what's happening here? It worked in the 1.3 app...

Comment: Did you look at the cache file? Does it show you a blank page with debug on 2?

Comment: No, the cached view file is not blank. It contains what would be expected.

Comment: In my app controller I changed:

public $cacheAction = true;

to

public $cacheAction = "1 hour";

and the views are now displaying from the cache instead of a blank page. I'm going to lower the timeframe and see what happens when a view expires in the cache.

Comment: Lowered the timeframe to 1 minute and the caching is working as expected. Woohoo!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! You should accept your answer so others visiting this question  in the future know the solution :)

Comment: Will do. Have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my app controller I changed: public $cacheAction = true; to public $cacheAction = "1 hour"; and the views are now displaying from the cache instead of a blank page. I'm gonna call this one fixed.

Comment: Worked for me too, but I did not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Completely blank page with no errors, messages...etc is almost always a space or extra character after the end of a close PHP tag in a PHP-only file.  Check your Controllers, Models, Behaviors...etc.  (It's good practice to just not close your PHP tags at all when in a PHP-only file.  This will keep the blank-screen thing from happening).

Comment: I'm glad you suggested that. I remember that error from way back in my 1.2 app. I actually went through every controller, model and behavior and made sure everything was kosher at the end of each file. Still nothing. One caveat is that I am using the DebugKit. But I've tried running the app with the kit unloaded and still nothing.